c# Microsoft.SharepointOnline.CSOM ExecuteQueryAsync not working
I'm using Microsoft.SharepointOnline.CSOM nugget and I can upload files withput any problems but if I change to ExecuteQueryAsync() method seems to be notworking. Simply program fails without any exception.
Code Example
FileCreationInformation fileCreation = new FileCreationInformation()
{
    ContentStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(file.SourceFilePath)),
    Overwrite = true,
    Url = file.FileName
};
var uploadFile = folder.Files.Add(fileCreation);
_clientContext.Load(uploadFile);
await _clientContext.ExecuteQueryAsync();

Same code using ExecuteQuery() is working properly.

Have you tried to add try-catch? try{await _clientContext.ExecuteQueryAsync();}catch(Exception ex){}

Yes, I have tried with try cath. The problem is that async seems to be not supported in console applications

Could you share the whole method and how do you call the method?
